# Sticky widget in the right sidebar is colliding with the footer

Tags: javascript, css, blogs

My blog has a stick widget at right sidebar after I scroll to end the widget must go to its position, but the sticky widget keeps on appearing and collides with the footer at the end.

The codes I use in my blog is as follows,

Javascript which I place above the `</body>` tag

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Sticky Widget
function makemeSticky(e){function t(){var e=s.getBoundingClientRect();e.top<0?(n.className=a+" makesticking",n.style.width=i+"px"):n.className=a}var n=document.getElementById(e),s=document.createElement("div");n.parentNode.insertBefore(s,n);var i=n.offsetWidth,a=n.className+" makesticky";window.addEventListener("scroll",t,!1)}makemeSticky("HTML6");
//]]>
</script>
```

CSS

```
.makesticking{background:none!important;position:fixed!important;top:25px;z-index:99;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);}
#HTML6 .widget-content {padding:0;margin:auto;}
```